# How to extract widgets from QHBoxLayout in Qt

Tags: qt

I have a TableWidget into which I add Widgets like this:

```
QLabel *l = new QLabel("TEST");
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout();

hbox->addWidget(l);
hbox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
hbox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
widget->setLayout(hbox);

ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 0, widget);
```

When a cell gets double clicked I capture the event and would like to figure out what QLabel it is.

But how do I extract it again or do I even have to?

Comment: A very simple way to figure out what QLabel it is, is to name them via QObject::setName. Another way would be storing pointers. I'd think either way would be fine. Not sure what you mean by "extract"?

Comment: What do you mean by storing pointers?

Comment: Where QLabel *l = new QLabel("TEST"); you can store the label in a list or however you plan on looking up the labels.

Comment: Ok and how do I find the match then? Looking up the label is my original problem!?

Comment: Pointer value by iterating over the list and comparing 'this'. It would happen inside the method that overrides the double click event.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way, since I can get the added widget with `ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(row,column)` in the double click event?

Comment: Perhaps telling more of what you're doing after you get the label you want will make the answer more clear.

Comment: I just need the text of the QLabel which is dynamically generated and will be processed on selection of the item in the tablewidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto    widget = ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(ui->tableWidget->currentRow(), ui->tableWidget->currentColumn()); // if mode is SingleSelection
auto    hbox = widget->layout();
auto    label = qobject_cast<QLabel *>(hbox->itemAt(0)->widget());
```